# Branch.io not showing the passed values on xcode 10 (reading the link is not working)

Tags: xcode10, branch.io

I implemented the Branch.io in my another new project, it's redirecting to the app correctly but the information which was I shared is not showing. The same code is implemented in another project it's working well the only difference is Xcode10.

On Xcode 10 link generations working fine but reading the link is not working.

**Expected behavior:-**
The link should redirect to the app and should show the information which was I share while generating the link.

**Actual behavior**
It's redirecting to the app and not showing the information.

**Steps to reproduce**
Implement the branch.io in xcode10 problem occurred.

Download the Sample of working and not working code below

Xcode 10 created the project not working
[sample_xcode_10](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1qu3wNngFeujKlsnVgeFMmg3hs99H_Jsy)

Xcode 9 created the project working
[sample_xcode_9](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1fSB3mPiZi9TJNrrhu2bprqnGadowe1vf)

Xcode 10 generated a link: "https://x5tu.app.link/QGHaY0p5GR"
working well in Xcode 9 not in xcode 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Xcode 10 or greater Apple updated Swift version to 4.2, on this Apple made some syntax changes in app life cycle `continue UserActity`. So in our case the app life cycle event not calling and not getting the details.

For this kindly update the `continue UserActity` method callback specification to `UIUserActivityRestoring` instead of `Any`.

**Previous Method:**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([Any]?) -> Void) -> Bool {return true}
```

**Working Method:**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
        print("Continue User Activity: ")
        if userActivity.activityType == NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb {
            let url = userActivity.webpageURL!
            print(url.absoluteString)
        }
        return true
    }
```

Comment: Thanks this approach worked for me., Thanks Muruganantham Manogaran

Answer (score 0):

Can you try enable logging and see what type of error responses you get? Feel free to reach out to integrations@branch.io with your IPA file if you'd like to us investigate further! Please be sure to include your Branch app ID in your email when you follow up.

Comment: Jackie Choi I already mailed last week and waiting for a solution.

Comment: Looks like the issue has been resolveed with one of our support engineers! Feel free to follow up on the thread there if you have any other questions.

Comment: Jackie Choi, still its opened, need support from your side, hope if you schedule the call we can close it ASAP thanks